# ASP.NET Core Web API - Custom Unique Email Validation using Data Annotation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I have Custom Unique Email validation using ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Entity Framework project

```
public class UserUniqueEmailValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public UserUniqueEmailValidator(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public bool IsUniqueUserEmailValidator(string email)
    {
        if (_dbContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()) == null) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I called it here:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email field is required. ERROR!")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email field must not exceed 100 characters.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.")]
    [UserUniqueEmailValidator(ErrorMessage = "Email already exists !!!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

But I got this error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'dbContext' of 'UserUniqueEmailValidator.UserUniqueEmailValidator(ApplicationDbContext)'

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like EF and dbContext is not properly defined at project startup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your own validation attribute, use the [Remote Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040) attribute.

Here is an example implementation

```
[Remote("ValidateEmailAddress","Home")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

The `validateEmailAddress` implementation

```
public IActionResult ValidateEmailAddress(string email)
{
    return Json(_dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Any(x => x.Email != email) ?
            "true" : string.Format("an account for address {0} already exists.", email));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error indicates: Validator's constructor contains the ApplicationDbContext parameter which is not valid;

Also, `IsUniqueUserEmailValidator`method has not been called ,so the codes inside it will never be executed

If you want to custom ValidationAttribute you could overrride  `protected virtual ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)`

and access ApplicationDbContext as below:

```
protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(
        object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var context = validationContext.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            //add your logical codes here



           return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```

For more details,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-attributes)